# Google Conversions - Tracking conversion sales with cookies

Tags: asp.net, cookies, google-analytics, tracking

We are currently using Google Conversion tracking as well as Google Analytics, but would like to implement a way to track actual sales from known conversions.

My original idea was to check for a specific cookie when the user finalizes their payment, and if it's found, save the OrderID and ConversionCode to a database. This idea went up in flames, of course, when I found out that the web server cannot actually access the cookies for conversions.

My next idea is to save my own cookie whenever the google conversion cookie is written. The cookie would contain a unique ID, which would make my first idea usable again.

Does anyone see any significant issues with this idea? Is there a more effective way of doing this that I don't know about? I'm still very new to Google tools (and cookies in general), so I could be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the order value via the `google_conversion_value` var in the tracking code. This obviously doesn't help with OrderID tracking, but should help you with your attribution model.

Further details here: http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=86277